# Error: bad memory at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/@ffmpeg.wasm/core-mt/dist/core.js:15:1

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, render

While deploying nodejs app on render.com i get this error  Error: bad memory  at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/@ffmpeg.wasm/core-mt/dist/core.js:15:1.

how to avoid this error i am using ffmpeg for merging audio with video.

full error

```
 /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/@ffmpeg.wasm/core-mt/dist/core.js:15
Oct 1 04:53:37 PM  Error("bad memory");var Aa=z.buffer;e.HEAP8=A=new Int8Array(Aa);e.HEAP16=C=new Int16Array(Aa);e.HEAP32=E=new Int32Array(Aa);e.HEAPU8=B=new Uint8Array(Aa);e.HEAPU16=wa=new Uint16Array(Aa);e.HEAPU32=F=new Uint32Array(Aa);e.HEAPF32=xa=new Float32Array(Aa);e.HEAPF64=ya=new Float64Array(Aa);za=z.buffer.byteLength;var H,Ba=[],Ca=[],Da=[],Ea=[],Fa=[],Ga=!1,Ha=0;function Ia(){return noExitRuntime||0<Ha}function Ja(){p||(e.noFSInit||I.Nb.Mc||I.Nb(),I.jd=!1,K.root=I.wb(K,{},null),Ka(Ca))}
Oct 1 04:53:37 PM  ^
Oct 1 04:53:37 PM  
Oct 1 04:53:37 PM  Error: bad memory
Oct 1 04:53:37 PM      at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/@ffmpeg.wasm/core-mt/dist/core.js:15:1
Oct 1 04:53:37 PM      at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/@ffmpeg.wasm/main/dist/index.js:165:64)
Oct 1 04:53:37 PM      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
Oct 1 04:53:37 PM      at fulfilled (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/@ffmpeg.wasm/main/dist/index.js:28:22)
```

my code

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();
import { readFile, writeFile } from "fs/promises";
import { FFmpeg } from "@ffmpeg.wasm/main";
import path from "path";

const currentDirectory = process.cwd();

const inputFilePath = path.join(currentDirectory, "video3.mp4");
const inputFilePath1 = path.join(currentDirectory, "wolf-howl-6310.mp3");
const outputFilePath = path.join(currentDirectory, "video3-2.mp4");

const ffmpeg = await FFmpeg.create({ core: "@ffmpeg.wasm/core-mt", log: true });

try {
  ffmpeg.fs.writeFile("/video3.mp4", await readFile(inputFilePath));
  ffmpeg.fs.writeFile("/wolf-howl-6310.mp3", await readFile(inputFilePath1));
  console.log(ffmpeg.version);
  await ffmpeg.run(
    "-i",
    "/wolf-howl-6310.mp3",
    "-i",
    "/video3.mp4",
    "-c",
    "copy",
    "-map",
    "0:a:0",
    "-map",
    "1:v:0",
    "/video3-2.mp4"
  );
  await writeFile(outputFilePath, ffmpeg.fs.readFile("/video3-2.mp4"));
  console.log("Conversion successful!");
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error:", error);
}

router.post("/", (req, res) => {});
export { router as Merge };
```

Comment: Off chance this works: are you running with --experimental-wasm-threads and --experimental-wasm-bulk-memory ? Referencing: https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/issues/66

Comment: @And1 no my build command is node index.js

Comment: Could be a thing to try then.